# How to install non Microsoft USB device driver on PC without admin rights?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, 7-zip

I am running Win 7x32 secured corporate laptop. My USB audio device has .exe installer file which is not possible to execute because of having no admin rights. Is it possible to embed driver files in the system without installation? All attempts of unpacking the .exe file got failed. 7zip is extracting files without extensions and Universal Extractor says that .exe file is 7zip self extracting archive.

Thank you
Ron

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking takes the ability to bypass the security of windows. Being it is a corporate laptop you won't be able to do anything without admin permissions. There is a way to access the local drive via command prompt before windows starts. but you would need to know where the files need to go and how to add keys to the registry via cmd. it would take a long time to because of all the typing and switching locations you would have to do. If you ask me its not worth the effort just to install an audio device so you can listen to music or videos when you are supposed to be working. Easiest answer...ask the administrator if s/he can install your audio device.

Answer (score 0):

IF you need this program to be installed see if you can edit boot priority in the bios and just live boot some other OS from a USB. That's what I've done on school computers when needing to bypass security.